# Java Webstart Stdin and Stdout

Tags: java, java-web-start

Is there a way to route Stdin and Stdout/Stderr to another process within java webstart?
What i want to do is have a java webstart application communicate with other processes on the desktop. Ideally i want to be able to send strings to the stdin of the java webstart which would the be processed and then output some result. Is this possible in java webstart?

The java webstart application would be invoked from the commandline or from within another application (through the open with default application feature supported in win7 and OSX).

Comment: What are "screen take arguments"? You can pass command line arguments using web start, is that what you want?

Comment: no, corrected grammar for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you invoke said java web start application so you have a possibility to connect it to anything?   The technology does not allow for this.

You can provide an URL argument and then read data from that.  An URL can point to a local file.

Comment: maybe i could open up a socket on the web start application and connect is to the address supplied in the arguments and us this socket as an inputstream... dont know if it would work though

Comment: Don't think so.  Perhaps you could edit your question to describe in more detail what you actually need to do?

Comment: Updated the question, maybe update the answer and ill accept it when i check back.

Comment: There is no feature in Java WebStart that allow you to connect to anything automatically.  You must do any of that kind on your own.  Note that Java WebStart provide an API to get outside the sandbox: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's different for webstart (because of permissions, perhaps) but in SE, you could do this using `System.setIn(InputStream in)` and `System.setOut(PrintStream out)`

Comment: Referencing inpustream and printstream to the other process would prove difficult without the reference :/